# Pitch Accent Confusion

Tags: pitch-accent

Occasionally, I hear the pitch accent of phrases that should be heard as 平板型 end up not being this way. Some examples are [卒業して](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMZyo95GfN0&t=7m37s)、[それは](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sEWPyebxEs&t=1m17s)、[これは](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlU8UAmTNb8&t=18m36s)、気がする、私は、私が. All of these words and phrases should be "flat". However, I have heard a couple instances where the pitch drops, such as in それは{LHL}、これは{LHL}、そつぎょうして{LHHHHHL}、きがする{LHHL}、わたしは{LHHL}、わたしが{LHHL}. Does anybody know what exactly is going on with these examples?

Comment: In your linked examples I hear the pitch go up at the end, not down, which is fine with 平板 if you’re trying to lead into a subsequent part of the sentence. Were the links meant to be an example of the pitch dropping?

Comment: Yes the links were meant to be an example of the pitch dropping. I thought the pitches were going down because they didn't seem to be as pronounced as the initial high pitch.

Comment: Oh, you know, I think there is a tiny bit of a drop *midway* into the last mora in your examples even though they start high. But my brain doesn’t hear this as lexical pitch, it hears it as sentence intonation. I don’t have a great answer here, hopefully someone else does!

Comment: Dialects. You don't have to get confused unless you stick to the standard accent. We understand all of them despite such different accents.

Comment: @Kai1212 I don't think you've accurately applied the pitch accent formatting. As far as I can hear, the drop in tone occurs on the final mora in the case of それ**は**, これ**は**, そつぎょうし**て**, etc. You have marked the downstep as the penultimate mora and I think this is incorrect.